# Firebase Admin - practical limit on the number of listeners

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am working with firebase-admin on Node.js, and initially we started with denormalizing most of the data. As the project grew, we started duplicating data for different views in one Node process. On one hand, this was done to simplify the client access to data, on the other hand to support more complex queries.

We are now running into a scenario where we need a lot of individual listeners. One example could be to listen to `child_added` on "`/chats/$uid/"` (for each user `$uid`) to compute certain statistics on on each user's chats. Obviously, the number of listeners then grows with the number of users.

So far everything works well, but how well does this approach scale? And more importantly, is there a practical limit on the number of listeners?

Comment: Listeners are quite inexpensive. See Rob's authoritative answer here(the Admin SDK is just another client for this context): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583746/firebase-limit-on-the-number-of-observers-listeners and some of these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635733/inexpensive-firebase-listeners/37638282, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274474/firebase-listeners-take-up-huge-amount-of-memory

Comment: If I understand correctly, it is fine having 1M+ listeners - as long as the data that is listened on fits in memory?

Comment: Each listener will also use memory. If you seriously need that many listeners, each is likely listening to very little data. So the listener's own memory usage might outweigh the actual data size. But it's all incredibly broad, so I can really only just repeat what Rob said already: there's no hard-coded limit on the number of listeners and that the overhead of listeners is quite small.

Comment: I would like to add that if you need 1M+ listeners, there's possibility that the data could be structured better or perhaps the workflow could be imagined in a different way. Without having a clear understanding why there's a need for that many listeners, we are just guessing.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The use case is as described above: each user has a collection of active chats (`/chats/${uid}`), and we would like to keep count of the active chats per user. One approach are transactions to increase the count whenever a chat is created, but it's likely to get into an inconsistent state (e.g. when client has a connection problem during the transaction). The ideal approach would be based on listeners on the server (child_added/child_changed), which just recomputes all the counts on server restart and keeps track.